# How do I setup a NIC for outgoing connections and the other to serve my Squid proxy?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, proxy, squid, nic

I have an internal network (`192.168.2.0/24`) that I'm supposed to connect to a proxy.

I've already installed and test(with a little traffic) an `Squid 3` cache/proxy server in a Ubuntu 12.04 box with this IP address: 192.168.2.102 `eth0`. Also, I have another physical NIC with IP 192.168.2.101 `eth1`.

The setup that I've done consists in the Ubuntu box going out to internet and serving the Squid in the same `eth0` NIC.

I have the concern when the all traffic come, this lonely NIC can't handle it.

So I want to setup the `eth1` to go out to the internet and the other one to serve the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question sounds a little confused, but I think you're asking for one interface to be used for external connectivity and the other interface to be dedicated to traffic for the squid clients. If so:

Make eth1 your default route (you didn't specify but this has a gateway that can route to/from the internet, right?)

```
ip route add default via 192.168.2.101
```

Then it's just a matter of having squid clients connect to eth0's address and use source based routing to ensure that responses to traffic coming in on eth0 (i.e. squid client traffic) also go out on eth0.

```
echo 1 squid >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default 192.168.2.102 table squid
ip rule add from 192.168.2.102 lookup squid
```